# Looking for data viewer in Visual Studio Code just as in Rstudio

Tags: visual-studio-code

In RStudio when you define vectors, dataframes, lists etc. you can see a preview of the data in the data viewer (upper right location in the picture where you can see "a  num [1:4] 1 2 3 4" etc.).

[Screenshot from RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBKJt.png)

Is there an extension/feature in Visual Code Studio that does the same? I was not able to find something. Searching online and in the VSCode extensions was not successful. I suspect that "data-viewer" may be the wrong keyword. Any help would be appreciated!